# Необходимо нарезать видео на фото с помощью Xabe.FFmpeg

Tags: c#, ffmpeg

Моя задача заключается в том чтобы каждую 50 мсек сохранять фрагмент видео как фото. Для этого я использую Xabe.FFmpeg. Я указываю ссылку на файл и мне выдают ошибку, при этом ссылку указываю верную.

Код взял из документации но немного изменил, потому что он не работал.

В чем я сделал ошибку?

```
Func<string, string> outputFileNameBuilder = (number) => { return 'p' + number + ".png"; };
IMediaInfo info = await FFmpeg.GetMediaInfo("test5.mkv").ConfigureAwait(false);
IVideoStream videoStream = info.VideoStreams.First()?.SetCodec(VideoCodec.png);

IConversionResult conversionResult = await FFmpeg.Conversions.New()
    .AddStream(videoStream)
    .ExtractEveryNthFrame(10, outputFileNameBuilder)
    .Start();
```

---

## UPDATE

**P.S.** я немного исправил код и понял в чем проблема, но не могу найти файл который нужно указывать тут `FFmpeg.SetExecutablesPath`

**Ошибка:**

```
System.IO.IOException: "Параметр задан неверно.:
'G:\С#\sourc\repos\proj\proj\bin\Debug\net6.0\Xabe.FFmpeg.5.2.0\Xabe.FFmpeg.5.2.0.nupkg'"
```

Comment: `мне выдают ошибку` какую? в какой строке кода? секрет?

Comment: `inputFilename` что содержит эта строка? Как вы думаете, что она должна содержать? Что в папке по указанному пути?

Comment: IMediaInfo info = await FFmpeg.GetMediaInfo(FFmpeg.ExecutablesPath).ConfigureAwait(false);
в этой строке ошибка. inputFilename это и есть ссылка на видео.

Comment: Вы прикалываетесь? Какая именно ошибка? Текст ее вставьте в пост с вопросом. Где лежат кодеки FFmpeg? Здесь `SetExecutablesPath(inputFilename)` не путь к файлу а путь к папке с кодеками должен быть. А здесь `GetMediaInfo(FFmpeg.ExecutablesPath)` путь к файлу. Вы все перепутали.

Comment: Executables - это папка с самими кодеками. Кодеки ставятся отдельно в сисьему, например из K-Lite Codec Pack, он их устанавливает в определенный каталог, вот туда и должен путь указывать, где лежит сам кодек ffmpeg.

Comment: Я исправил но теперь новая ошибка в строчке            
IConversionResult conversionResult = await FFmpeg.Conversions.New()
                .AddStream(videoStream)
                .ExtractEveryNthFrame(10, outputFileNameBuilder)
                .Start();
Ошибка: System.ArgumentException: "Path cannot be the empty string or all whitespace. Arg_ParamName_Name"

Comment: Отлаживайте, в тексте исключения всё очевидно написано.